# Compiling and running functions by name in Scala?

Tags: scala, classpath, scala-2.10, scala-2.9, scalac

Following along in this Masters thesis`[1]` to learn parsing in Scala, but can't figure out how to get this example working (see pages 28-29):

```scala
import util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

trait ArithParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def expr: Parser[Any] = term ~ rep("+" ~ term | "-" ~ term)
    def term              = factor ~ rep("*" ~ factor | "/" ~ factor)
    def factor            = floatingPointNumber ^^ {_.toDouble} | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
}

object ArithParserCLI extends ArithParser {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        for (arg <- args) {
            println("Input: " + arg)
            println("Output: " + parseAll(expr, arg))
        }
    }
}
```

`[1]` [E. Labun, “Combinator Parsing in Scala,” Technische Hochschule Mittelhessen, 2012.](http://labun.com/fh/ma.pdf)

Unfortunately I cannot get it to run in either Scala 2.9.3 or Scala 2.11.0-M4:

```
> scala29 ArithParserCLI "10.5 - 4*2"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to
run target: ArithParserCLI
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)

        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

So then trying with the 2.11 scalac and scala:

```
> scala ArithParserCLI "10.5 - 4*2"
No such file or class on classpath: ArithParserCLI
```

Comment: FYI: Was just able to get it to work at the `sbt console` with `ArithParserCLI.main(Array("10.5 - 4*2"))`, `:)`. Would be great to also get it to work with `scalac` and `scala` though…

Comment: Looks like build/classpath problem rather than code problem

Comment: Which can be fixed; how?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code - are you actually compiling it with `scalac` before running it?

```
 scalac ArithParserCLI.scala  # or whatever your source file is named
 scala ArithParserCLI "10.5 - 4*2"
```

As an aside, if you plan on doing any significant coding in Scala theb `sbt` is highly recommended. You can run the following code in `sbt` as well:

```
 # Assuming the current directory contains only one scala source file with a 
 # main method:
 sbt 'run "10.5 - 4*2"'
```

Comment: Got [these errors](http://pastebin.com/0aDtmLCQ) on ` sbt 'run "10.5 - 4*2"'`. You have seen my errors from scalac -> scala.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just taken the source code without any change and done the following:

```
[root@centos scala]# scalac parser.scala
[root@centos scala]# scala ArithParserCLI "10.5 - 4*2"
Input: 10.5 - 4*2
Output: [1.11] parsed: ((10.5~List())~List((-~(4.0~List((*~2.0))))))
```

scala version 2.9.2. So, the error is likely in your local configuration.